# javascript using REST

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am quite new to CRM dynamics 2016. I need help in writing the following javascript code. I have two entities Capacity and Scenario . In the Capacity form,there is a lookup field belonging  Scenario entity i.e on selecting the lookup value for scenario the rest fields belonging to scenario entity should auto populate.They dnt have mappings.

// JavaScript source code

```
function GetScenarioData()

{

var scenario = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("spa_scenario").getValue();

if (scenario != null)

{
    var scenarioID = scenario[0].id;
    var scenarioName = scenario[0].name;ST
    SDK.REST.retrieveRecord(scenarioID, "msdyn_project", null, null, function getDetails(data) {

        var scenarioDescription = data.spa_ScenarioDescription;
        var organizationPathID = data.spa_OrganationPath.Id;
        var organizationName = data.spa_OrganationPath.Name;
        var capacityChampionID = data.spa_CapacityChampion.Id;
        var capacityChampionName = data.spa_CapacityChampion.Name;
        var fiscalCycleID = data.spa_FiscalCycle.Id;
        var fiscalCycleName = data.spa_FiscalCycle.Name;
        var budgetID = data.spa_Budget.Id;
        var budgetName = data.spa_Budget.Name;
        var ionfunding = data.spa_ImpactofNotFunding;
        }, errorHandler);
}

}

function errorHandler(error)
{
    alert("Error:" + error.message);
}
```

I have wriiten this code so far ..which doesnt help me retrieve. Please help.

Comment: Could you share whats the value of data ?

Comment: i though its an inbuilt JS functionality

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetScenarioData()

{

var scenario = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("spa_scenario").getValue();

if (scenario != null)
{
    var scenarioID = scenario[0].id;
    var scenarioName = scenario[0].name;
    SDK.REST.retrieveRecord(scenarioID,
        scenario[0].entityType,
        "spa_ScenarioDescription,spa_OrganationPath,spa_CapacityChampion,spa_FiscalCycle,spa_Budget,spa_ImpactofNotFunding",
        null,
        function getDetails(data) {
            var scenarioDescription = data.spa_ScenarioDescription;
            var organizationPathID = data.spa_OrganationPath.Id;
            var organizationName = data.spa_OrganationPath.Name;
            var capacityChampionID = data.spa_CapacityChampion.Id;
            var capacityChampionName = data.spa_CapacityChampion.Name;
            var fiscalCycleID = data.spa_FiscalCycle.Id;
            var fiscalCycleName = data.spa_FiscalCycle.Name;
            var budgetID = data.spa_Budget.Id;
            var budgetName = data.spa_Budget.Name;
            var ionfunding = data.spa_ImpactofNotFunding;
        },
    errorHandler);
}

}

function errorHandler(error)
{
    alert("Error:" + error.message);
}
```